# How to delay Hide/Show events until Iframe loads after a submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a script that shows 2 divs and hides 1 div after a user submits a form. The form's target is an Iframe on the same page. The Iframe takes a while to load.

I would like to delay the Hide/Show events until the Iframe loads. I was able to do this with a loading animation, but I am not sure how to do this with the Hide/Show script.

This is the Hide/Show script

```
$(function () {
    $('#form_710370').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // add this
        $('#form_container').hide()
        $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<div id="mydivhide1">1111</div>
<div id="mydivhide2">2222</div>

<div id="form_container">
    <form id="form_710370"  target="iframe" method="post" convert.php">
        <input id="Website" name="url1" type="text" value=""/> 
        <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form> 
</div>
```

This is the relevant CSS

```
#mydivhide1 {display:none;}
#mydivhide2 {display:none;}
```

Comment: show or hide div in the iframe `load()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Detect your iFrame has loaded :**

```
$('#YourIframe').load(function(){

});
```

**On your form submitted :**

```
$("#form_710370").on('ajax:complete',function(){

});
```

Comment: Do those both belong in the same script? If yes, where? I am just learning and I still am not sure about what goes on top or bottom of a script.

Comment: After your `.submit()` gonna be ok @MichaelFalciglia

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
timeout = setTimeout(function () {
   $('#form_container').hide();
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your hide and show code inside iframe load() function.

```
$('#frame').load(function(){
   $('#form_container').hide();
   $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// delay
setTimeout(function () {
    // after delay 
    $('#form_container').animate({
        'height': '0px'
    }, '400', 'swing', function () {
        // finish animate fadeIn
        $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').fadeIn('400');
    });
}, '700');
```

Hope is help